# Birth time after Modify time in stat command

Tags: rsync, timestamps, stat

I have a folder with a Birth time later than its Modify time:

```
  File: Pictures
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 804h/2052d  Inode: 31724953    Links: 4
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/  alexis)   Gid: ( 1000/  alexis)
Access: 2021-01-08 13:11:30.465322886 -0300
Modify: 2018-12-07 22:46:58.000000000 -0300
Change: 2020-04-04 01:47:16.276535539 -0300
 Birth: 2020-04-04 01:41:07.436520483 -0300
```

Could you explain to me how this can happen? I guess it may be related with an rsync operation.

Comment: Did you tried rsync with -t optin to preserve timestamps ?

Comment: Yes, that is. I probably used -a option that implies -t. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Birth time and change time are controlled by the operating system, and can’t be altered except by performing the operations they trace. Thus the birth time always reflects the date and time of creation (as known to the system when the event occurred).

Access time and modification time are set by the operating system when the corresponding events occur, but they can also be overridden, using [`utimensat`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utimensat.2.html) for example. If you copied the directory from some other location, while preserving timestamps, then the tool you used to copy it would have set the modification timestamp to match the original.

You can see this yourself:

```
rm -f test
touch -d "-1 day" test
stat test
```