# Why rsync on Linux does not preserve all timestamps (creation time)?

Tags: linux, rsync, file-copy, timestamps, macos

I am using the current rsync 3.2.3 version and when I run `stat` command it shows me this info for my file.

```
stat '/test.txt'
File: /test.txt
Size: 0     Blocks: 0
IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 11949
Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/liveuser)   Gid: ( 1000/liveuser)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2021-02-24 03:17:27.142676494 +0100
Modify: 2021-02-24 03:17:27.142676494 +0100
Change: 2021-02-24 03:17:27.142676494 +0100
Birth: 2021-02-24 03:17:27.142676494 +0100
```

I want to preserve Access, Modify and Birth timestamps. Use this command in rsync

```
rsync --atimes --times --crtimes
```

or

```
rsync -UtN
```

The problem creation time (--crtimes) is not preserved on Linux. It automatically sets to the current transfer time.

How can I change the behaviour on Linux? I want to preserve all 3 timestamps for my copied files and folders.

If I do the same on macOS it works without problems.

**EDIT**

On macOS 10.13 and macOS 11 I just need to install homebrew and then I can get the latest rsync 3.2.3. By default, macOS has a very outdated rsync version 2.6.9 integrated.

1. Open Terminal
2. Install Homebrew

   `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`
3. Install rsync

   `brew install rsync`

Comment: What filesystem are you using on the Linux system?

Comment: ext4 and Btrfs on the Linux system.

Comment: @Olea.2fmao Do you mean `rsync` from **ext4** to **btrfs** (cross file system), or from **ext4** to **ext4** and from **btrfs** to **btrfs** (same file system), where both same FS tries fail.

Comment: *ext4 to ext4*, *ext4 to Btrfs*, *Btrfs to Btrfs* and *Btrfs to ext4* The creation time is not preserve and it is set to the current transfer time.

Comment: Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61586/how-to-tell-rsync-to-preserve-time-stamp-on-files-when-source-tree-has-a-mounted

Comment: Possible related/duplicate question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628261/birth-time-after-modify-time-in-stat-command

Comment: @AndreWildberg No. It doesn't work.

Comment: Btw, macOS != Linux. In fact it’s more BSD than anything else. Similar, but notably different in a lot of ways!!

Answer (score 6):

### Linux

**crtime** tells when the file was created in this filesystem. It was never intended to indicate when the content might have been created somewhere else.

### MacOS

`rsync` can be "patched" on MacOS. If you compile `rsync` with the patches fileflags, crtimes, hfs-compression then `rsync` can handle OS X metadata and preserve the original file's birthtime on the new file. Note that **st_birthtime** is only available in the 64 bit inode variants. See `man 2 stat`.

It's possible there are patched versions of `rsync` for Linux around. Though I am not aware of any.

Comment: On my macOS 10.13 and macOS 11 I just need to install homebrew and then I can get the latest rsync 3.2.3. By default, macOS has a very outdated rsync version `2.6.9` integrated. 

Install Homebrew
`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Install rsync 
`brew install rsync`

Comment: Then on macOS I can preserve all 3 timestamps (Access, Modify and Birth), on Linux only Birth does not work.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem creation time (--crtimes) is not preserved on Linux. It automatically sets to the current transfer time.

While you can perfectly query crtime, there's no API to set it in Linux unfortunately: https://linux.die.net/man/2/utimes .

> How can I change the behaviour on Linux? I want to preserve all 3 timestamps for my copied files and folders.

Check this question: [Copying or restoring crtime for files/directories on ext4fs filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/591384/copying-or-restoring-crtime-for-files-directories-on-ext4fs-filesystem)